# Accessing a text Input inside iFrame (Google Forms) - Javascript

Tags: javascript, iframe

Cutting to the chase:

I have a Google Forms survey, and basically I need to dynamically edit one of its text-inputs.

The Forms survey is actually 1 out of 6 possible surveys, so Javascript adds it:
`'<iframe name="survey"  id="ifrm" src="https://spreadsheets.google.com/spreadsheet/embeddedform?formkey=dHpYM1NvTFN4OElNWnBJWUtjdHhld2c6MQ" width="760" height="623" frameborder="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0">Loading...</iframe>'`

The trouble is accessing that textbox - I used `setTimeout()` to wait until the iFrame is loaded properly. And then I want to do this:

```
function writeEncoded() {
        alert("now attempting to inject");


        var iF = document.getElementById('ifrm');
        alert( iF); 

        //works up to here
        var form = iF.contentWindow.document; //does not run.
        alert (form);
        form.getElementById('entry_3').value = "Hi";

    }
```

Any ideas what's going wrong?
Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You’re seeing [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) in action.

On the web, content on one website is [mostly](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.postMessage) not allowed to interact with content on another.

Since the `iframe` is loaded from `https://spreadsheets.google.com` and (I’m guessing) your webpage is on another website (like `http://example.com/`), your JavaScript can’t see anything inside the `iframe` (and Google’s JavaScript can’t see anything on your webpage).

Why? Same Origin Policy is meant to protect you. Without it, I could load `google.com` into an `iframe` on my website and, with JavaScript, read your email address (if you’re logged in). Or, I could load `facebook.com` and read your name and quite a bit of other personal information out of the page.

Comment: Ah, thanks for the tip. I'll just copy down Google's Survey Form and make it into htmls on my own server.

Answer (score 0):

The iframe is unusual in that it "lives" in two place in the browser javascript heirarchy.
It's part of the window.frames collection because it's a kind of frame AND it's also a part of the document tree because it's an element. You can use the following line to access the element iframe and then do what you want to with it.

```
window.frames[x].document.getelementById('')
```

with x being 0 if there are no other iframes in the document.